# Gyrojet pistol vs forensics?

Tags: weapons, crime, law-enforcement

How would ballistic evidence be gathered against against a gryojet pistol in which there would not be the clear marks left on the bullet due to the barrel? I'm thinking of this in a science fiction context in which they are significantly more common than they are now.

While a gryojet pistol would probably make a fairly bad murder weapon in most cases due to its slow velocity at short range, it would seemingly have an immunity to forensics if used properly.

Comment: There are a lot of these around, are there?  Else investigators would simply need to track (via collector networks) who has one...

Comment: Also, this is not (IMO) a `hard-science` type question; in fact, given the scarcity of Gyrojet weapons and the much greater scarcity of their ammunition, I think it's opinion-based.

Comment: How would evidence be gathered against a shotgun in which there would not be the clear marks left on the pellets due to the barrel? And there are very many more shotguns than gyrojets. I somehow believe that police don't just shrug and say, well, he was shot with a shotgun, no way we can convict the shooter, let's forget it.

Comment: given how hard it is to get gyrojets ammunition (~$100 + per bullet) that alone might make identifying the killer far easier. Also given that gyrojets are unique in the bullet taking the primer with them matching to the firing pin would be a better approach. but there is no way to get hard-science for a hypothetical question.

Comment: Maybe taggants in the propellent? It seems like the propellent gets ejected along the path. Maybe methods similar to gunshot residue?

Answer (score 1):

Weapon forensics is not just rifling.

- [DNA](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32977300/) can be gathered from normal cartridge cases. Presumably from gyrojets as well.
- The rounds are fired by relatively normal firing pins hitting primer caps. These leave [imprints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forensic_firearm_examination#Examination_of_cartridges) which can be analyzed.

Comment: Since these things are so rare and not used often, I would add "Was this gun fired recently? When?", Since I expect there are relative firm forensics behind that idea.